# How to get the date formate from the time stamp in swift

Tags: swift, timestamp

I want to get the date formate from the time stamp.so  I am getting the timestamp is from the firebase database. so I am getting this output when it is retrieved from the firestore 2018-08-31T05:33:31.408Z . so I want to format the timestamp in the form "Aug 2018", 11.39 AM. so I tried to convert it with this code

```
let timestamp = deyaPaybalance.value(forKey: "timestamp") as! NSArray
print("timestamp is",timestamp)
//let len = timestamp.count
for element in timestamp {
    let ele = element
    let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    //print("date is",date1!)
    formatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate,
                               .withTime,
                               .withDashSeparatorInDate,
                               .withColonSeparatorInTime]
    let date2 = formatter.date(from: ele as! String)
    print("timestamp with date is",date2!)
    print("element is",ele)
}
```

But I am getting this type of output 2018-09-22 09:29:11 +0000 . So how to solve that one.

Comment: You are actually parsing the timestamp to a Date Object. Now if you want the date object to format any other way take a DateFormatter Variable, set dateFormat of the formatter and get the string from the date. That will convert the date to the expected string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually parsing the timestamp to a Date Object. Now if you want the date object to format any other way take a DateFormatter Variable, set dateFormat of the formatter and get the string from the date. That will convert the date to the expected string.

```
let anotherFormatter = DateFormatter()
anotherFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy, h:mm a"
anotherFormatter.string(from: date2)
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you JAHID